# How specifying a point the location of the receiver in view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How specifying a point the location of the receiver in view for iphone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns the current location of the receiver in the coordinate system of the given view.

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

The view object in whose coordinate system you want the touch located. A custom view that is handling the touch may specify self to get the touch location in its own coordinate system. Pass nil to get the touch location in the window’s coordinates.

In Return Value a point specifying the location in view.

This method returns the current location of a **UITouch** object in the coordinate system of the specified view. Because the touch object might have been forwarded to a view from another view, this method performs any necessary conversion of the touch location to the coordinate system of the specified view.